# R Error: unexpected ',' in "write(txt2, file = ("C:/Users/User/Documents/html","

Tags: r

I received this error when exporting html into text. I dont really understand what cause this. Please help me with it. Thank you in advanced

```
 Error: unexpected ',' in "        write(txt2, file = ("C:/Users/User/Documents/html","
```

to export converted html in text.

Below is my code in R:

```
        write(txt2, file = ("C:/Users/User/Documents/html", txt2.txt))
```

the objective is to convert html webpage into text and export it into working directory using R.
The last line of code is causing this error which i don't know why.

Comment: Please try to reduce this down to only the most relevant parts of the code (basically only the final line), and supply example values of the variables you are trying to use for the data and filename. It's not clear what `txt2.txt` is supposed to be (a string? a separate variable?).

Comment: Just define "pass" `file` correctly, for example using `write(x, file = "C:/Users/User/Documents/html/txt2.txt")` or like `write(x, file = paste0("C:/Users/User/Documents/html/",'txt3.txt'))`